# Why is only one Flask teardown_request function being called when view raises Exception?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

This simple application, has two `teardown_request` handlers, and I'd expect both of them to be called for every request, no matter what happens in the view implementation, as per the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.teardown_request)

```
import flask
import werkzeug.exceptions

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.teardown_request
def teardown1(response):
    print "Teardown 1"
    return response

@app.teardown_request
def teardown2(response):
    print "Teardown 2"
    return response

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "chunky bacon"

@app.route("/httpexception")
def httpexception():
    raise werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest("no bacon?")

@app.route("/exception")
def exception():
    raise Exception("bacoff")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000)
```

However, when I run it and make requests to the three views in turn, I get the following output:

```
Teardown 2
Teardown 1
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2011 18:53:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Teardown 2
Teardown 1
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2011 18:53:27] "GET /httpexception HTTP/1.1" 400 -

Teardown 2
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2011 18:53:33] "GET /exception HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Only one of the `teardown_request` functions is being called when an exception that is not derived from `werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException` is raised by the last view. Any ideas why, or is this a bug in flask?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just discovered the answer myself.

The `teardown_request` functions are not supposed to take a response and return a response, the way [`after_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.after_request) does. They apparently take an argument which is usually `None` unless an `Exception` which does not derive from `HttpException` is raised by the view, in which case they are passed that.

Apparently they also **must not** return said exception or you'll get the broken behaviour that I demonstrated.

To fix, the app's `teardown_request` functions should look like this:

```
@app.teardown_request
def teardown1(exc):
    print "Teardown 1 {0!r}".format(exc)

@app.teardown_request
def teardown2(exc):
    print "Teardown 2 {0!r}".format(exc)
```

Which then gives the expected output for all three views:

```
Teardown 2 None
Teardown 1 None
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2011 19:20:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Teardown 2 None
Teardown 1 None
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2011 19:20:10] "GET /httpexception HTTP/1.1" 400 -

Teardown 2 Exception('bacoff',)
Teardown 1 Exception('bacoff',)
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2011 19:20:18] "GET /exception HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

(with the addition of some extra debug to print what gets passed to the `teardown_request` handlers)